# Uncaught TypeError : Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript

so I try to change the background of a box but i get that.
please I need your instead of all answers I have read on this page,no of them don't resolve my probleme.
I thing it is because I am a novice in programming.
this is the code:

```
        <button onclick="changeBG('box1','#F0F');">Magenta</button>

        <div id="box1"> content in box1</div>

        <style type="text/css">
                    div#box1{
                        background-color: #9dceff;
                        width:400px;
                        height:200px;   
                    }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                        function changeBG(el,color){
                           var elem = document.getElementById('el');
                           elem.style.transition ="background 1.0s linear 0s ";
                           elem.style.background =color;
                        }
        </script>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you use

```
var elem = document.getElementById('el');
```

`elem` will be the element with `id="el"`.

You should use the following instead:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(el);
```

if you want `elem` to be them element with an `id` of the string in `el` variable.

Comment: thank you very match,your answer is very useful.God bless you